# Remove quote signs from multiple strings

Tags: python

I am attempt to rename files which replace 'VV' with VV

```
alist = ["py'VV'1.File.md",
 "py'VV'3.Database.md",
 "py'VV'Projects.md",
 "py'VV'2.Input.md"]
```

my desired output:

```
newlist = ["pyVV1.File.md",
 "pyVV3.Database.md",
 "pyVVProjects.md",
 "pyVV2.Input.md"]
```

My solution

```
[i.replace("'VV'",'VV') for i in alist]
Out[158]: ['pyVV1.File.md', 'pyVV3.Database.md', 'pyVVProjects.md', 'pyVV2.Input.md']
```

How to handle it in a magic access to disappear the quote`' '`automatically.

for instances:

```
In [163]: eval('str')
Out[163]: str
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? The list comprehension looks correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove quotes:

```
import  re

alist = ["py'VV'1.File.md",
 "py'VV'3.Database.md",
 "py'Pass'Projects.md",
 "py'VX'2.Input.md"]

pattern = r'\'(.*?)\''
blist = [re.sub(pattern, lambda x : x.group(1), s) for s in alist]

print(blist)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the OP actually wants, I don't see how this is a solution to any imaginable interpretation. Have you tested it on the "counter example" you propose under the other answer? What your solution does is worse!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
[x.replace("'", "") for x in alist]
#O/p: ['pyVV1.File.md', 'pyVV3.Database.md', 'pyVVProjects.md', 'pyVV2.Input.md']
```

Your's is correct also, but if you want to replace any single quotes from each string in your list then above should work. (it will replace "'VV'" with "VV" and also "'anychar'" to "anychar").Hope it helps.